# easing functions for bell curves?

Tags: function, math, animation

[Robert Penner's easing functions](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/) make it easy to create a variety of animation behaviors by moving *X* between 0 and 1, as the resultant *Y* moves starts at 0 and ends at 1.  [Examples here.](http://hosted.zeh.com.br/tweener/docs/en-us/misc/transitions.html)

I am wondering if there is such a set of functions for bell curves?  Given *X* between 0 and 1, these functions would return *Y* between 0 and 1, starting at 0 and ending at 0.

I've not seen such a collection, but before I get going on fitting parabolas *so everything fits between 0 and 1 on both axes*, I thought I'd check here first.

Comment: Hm, unlike the other functions, a Gaussian never hits 0 though unless it's vertically displaced, so if such an easing function exists, expect vertical displacement (or at least, some kind of a cutoff threshold at the tail) to be a parameter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are lots of common bell-shaped functions *f* on [0, 1]; I assume you want them to satisfy f(0) = f(1) = f'(0) = f'(1) = 0 and f(1/2) = 1. Examples:

- Any symmetric [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) density function, for any parameters α = β > 1, is bell-shaped and has zero derivative at the endpoints. That is, `f(x) = 4^α * x^(α - 1) * (1 - x)^(α - 1)`, where `4^α` is a constant to scale it so that it goes up to 1:

  [image: beta]
- Pick a segment of a sinusoidal function, starting and ending at adjacent troughs, and translating/scaling as desired. Example: `f(x) = (sin(2 * π * (x - 1/4)) + 1) / 2`:

  [image: sine]