# Why does rand() + rand() produce negative numbers?

Tags: c, random

I observed that `rand()` library function when it is called just once within a loop, it almost always produces positive numbers.

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", rand());
}
```

But when I add two `rand()` calls, the numbers generated now have more negative numbers.

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    printf("%d = %d\n", rand(), (rand() + rand()));
}
```

Can someone explain why I am seeing negative numbers in the second case?

PS: I initialize the seed before the loop as `srand(time(NULL))`.

Comment: `rand()` can't be negative...

Comment: rand() + rand() can owerflow

Comment: What is `RAND_MAX` for your compiler? You can usually find it in `stdlib.h`. (Funny: checking `man 3 rand`, it bears the one-line description "bad random number generator".)

Comment: what if u give unsigned int or long long in place of int as specifier?

Comment: @SagarKar: That would be undefined behavior.  `rand()+rand()` is an `int`.

Comment: do what every sane programmer would do `abs(rand()+rand())`. I'd rather have a positive UB than a negative one! ;)

Comment: @hexa: that is no sotution for the UB, as the occurs for the addition already. You cannot make UB become _defined behaviour_. A _sane_ progrtammer would avoid UB like hell.

Comment: Even without overflow, `rand() + rand()` would produce a triangular distribution (like rolling two dice), not a uniform one.  That's probably not what you want.

Comment: What do you mean "it **almost** always produces positive numbers" on its own? `rand()` is defined to produce numbers in a specific range (between 0 and RAND_MAX), so the only non-positive numbers you should be seeing would be zeros. So where are you seeing any negative numbers in the first case?

Comment: @dan04: but with overflow with RAND_MAX equal to INT_MAX, abs(rand() + rand()) has a uniform distribution again.

Comment: Also, consider `arc4random()` when generating multiple random numbers.

Comment: Also consider that `rand()+rand()` is not yielding the same random distribution between 0 and 2*RAND_MAX, for the same reason that rolling a 6-sided die twice yields different results than rolling a 12-sided die once.

Comment: @Olaf didnt you get that taste of sarcasm?

Comment: @Zaibis: Sorry, I'm not good at that even in my own language sometimes :-)

Comment: @XiangJi: "should be ..." Well, I should have gotten 1 cent (whatever currency) for that. There's a plethora of people out there who do not have an idea about the binary arithmetic and the C standard. Most think 2s complement is the only representation of signed values - if they think about that at all.

Comment: @XiangJi: There is no problem in asking "a" question, basic or complex. You can miss a thing here and there.

Comment: **Hint**: try saving the random numbers to variables, and printing the pairs with a negative sum.

Comment: @Olaf what is a UB? What are you talking about?

Comment: @badmad Sure sure. That's what SO is about. Just a bit surprised it got this many upvotes and became the top question in the newsletter.

Comment: @hellyale:[_undefined bahaviour_](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p1)

Answer (score 547, accepted):

`rand()` is defined to return an integer between `0` and `RAND_MAX`.

```
rand() + rand()
```

could overflow. What you observe is likely a result of [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) caused by integer overflow.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80565/discussion-on-answer-by-blue-moon-why-does-rand-rand-produce-negative-numb).

Comment: Actually this would depend if `rand` returns a signed or unsigned integer, as overflow for unsigned integers is well defined.

Comment: @JakubArnold: the standard defined `rand()` to be `int`.

Comment: @Olaf oh sorry I didn't notice it was a C specific question, thought it was language agnostic.

Comment: @JakubArnold: How that as overflow behaviour is specified by each language differently? Python for instance has none (well, up to available memory), as int just grows.

Comment: @Olaf It depends how a language decides to represent signed integers. *Java* had no mechanism to detect integer overflow (until java 8) and defined it to wrap around and *Go* uses 2's complement representation only and defines it legal for signed integer overflows. C obviously supports more than 2's complement.

Comment: @BlueMoon: That was exatly my point. However, carefull, otherwise we will be moved to chat:-) (C does allow other than 2s complement, but gcc does actually not, btw.)

Comment: @JakubArnold even if it returned unsigned; using `%d` to print an unsigned integer is undefined.

Comment: And as commented below? that it can overflow. When that happens it goes from the largest positive number it can take, directly to the negative equal.

Comment: @EvanCarslake No, that's not a universal behaviour. What you say is about 2's complement representation. But C language allows for other representations too. The C language specification says signed integer overflow is *undefined*. So in general, no program should rely on such behaviour and need to code carefully to not cause signed integer overflow. But this is not applicable for unsigned integers as they would "wrap-around" in a well-defined (reduction modulo 2) manner. [continued]...

Comment: This is the quote from C standard related to signed integer overflow: **If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: @EvanCarslake moving a bit away from the question the C compilers do use the standard and for signed integers they can assume that `a + b > a` if they know that `b > 0`. They can also assume that if there is later executed statement `a + 5` then current value is lower then `INT_MAX - 5`. So even on 2's complement processor/interpreter without traps program might not behave as if `int`s were 2's complement without traps.

Answer (score 91):

The problem is the addition. [`rand()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.2.1) returns an `int` value of `0...RAND_MAX`. So, if you add two of them, you will get up to `RAND_MAX * 2`. If that exceeds `INT_MAX`, the result of the addition overflows the valid range an `int` can hold. Overflow of signed values is undefined behaviour and may lead to your keyboard talking to you in foreign tongues.

As there is no gain here in adding two random results, the simple idea is to just not do it. Alternatively you can cast each result to `unsigned int` before the addition if that can hold the sum. Or use a larger type. Note that `long` is not necessarily wider than `int`, the same applies to `long long` if `int` is at least 64 bits!

Conclusion: Just avoid the addition. It does not provide more "randomness". If you need more bits, you might concatenate the values `sum = a + b * (RAND_MAX + 1)`, but that also likely requires a larger data type than `int`.

As your stated reason is to avoid a zero-result: That cannot be avoided by adding the results of two `rand()` calls, as both can be zero. Instead, you can just increment. If `RAND_MAX == INT_MAX`, this cannot be done in `int`. However, `(unsigned int)rand() + 1` will do very, very likely. Likely (not definitively), because it does require `UINT_MAX > INT_MAX`, which is true on all implementations I'm aware of (which covers quite some embedded architectures, DSPs and all desktop, mobile and server platforms of the past 30 years).

**Warning:**

Although already sprinkled in comments here, please note that adding two random values does *not* get a uniform distribution, but a triangular distribution like rolling two dice: to get `12` (two dice) both dice have to show `6`. for `11` there are already two possible variants: `6 + 5` or `5 + 6`, etc.

So, the addition is also bad from this aspect.

Also note that the results `rand()` generates are not independent of each other, as they are generated by a [*pseudorandom number generator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). Note also that the standard does not specify the quality or uniform distribution of the calculated values.

Comment: thx. the reason i was adding was to avoid '0' as the random number in my code. rand()+rand() was the quick dirty solution which readily came to my mind.

Comment: @badmad: So what if both calls return 0?

Comment: what are the chances? rarer compared to using one rand()

Comment: @badmad: I just wonder if `UINT_MAX > INT_MAX != false` is guranteed by the standard. (Sounds likely, but not sure if required). If so, you can just cast a single result and increment (in that order!).

Comment: @badmad: Consider this, ideally a random number generator needs a uniform distribution. This means that all numbers have equal chances to appear. Now, for rand() to be 0, that is a single value. But, rand() + rand() can yield 0 in 2+ ways: both calls return 0 or both calls return half INT_MAX meaning when they sum the result will be 0. In this scenario, you are now twice as likely to get 0. However, if RAND_MAX is larger than half INT_MAX, more values can sum to 0. In essence, the sum of two uniform distribution is not uniform.

Comment: @NicholasFrechette: It is not twice as likely to get two `0` in a row. p(0) = 1/(RAND_MAX + 1). p(0, 0) = p(0) * p(0).

Comment: There is gain in adding multiple random numbers when you want a non-uniform distribution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492259/get-a-random-number-focused-on-center

Comment: @Cœur: Yes, but that is not the point here. You still have to care about overflow/UB. However, I  will correct my answer a bit - thanks. A general problem here is to split between algorithm and implementation - this question is clearly about implementation.

Comment: to avoid 0, a simple "while result is 0, re-roll" ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac: There are applications you cannot allow for a loop (yeah, it is very unlikely, but - yes). My point is, however more about the int overflow.

Comment: Not only is adding them a bad way to avoid 0, but it also results in a non-uniform distribution. You get a distribution like the results of rolling dice: 7 is 6 times as likely as 2 or 12.

Comment: @Olaf [Re:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821406/why-does-rand-rand-produce-negative-numbers/30821874#comment49690053_30821874) As I read §6.2.5 §6.2.5 9  "The range of nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the corresponding unsigned integer type" implies `UINT_MAX >= INT_MAX`, not  `UINT_MAX > INT_MAX`.  Character types have other restrictions.   The only system I have encountered with `INTn_MAX == UINTn_MAX` was BITD on an extra wide type where the underlying code only handled signed math, so the widest unsigned type had a padded bit instead of a sign bit.

Comment: @chux: Thanks for pointing that out. I actually thought I had covered that, but maybe my wording was a bit unclear. I actually did not state the `>` was guaranteed, but that it was a necessary requirement for the addition not to invoke UB. When I wrote this answer I was pretty new in standard nit-pickying. Anyway, I hope the new wording is a bit more clear.

Comment: @Olaf Nice update.  IMO, Code can assert `Utype_MAX/2 == Stype_MAX` unless one also wants high portability to   1's complement, sign-magnitude, 9-bit bytes and other exotic/historic platforms.  Interesting exercises, yet ever less relevant.

Comment: No need for the division and potentially it adds another problem. The original condition `>` is sufficient. Just use a `_Static_assert` in the code. But that is a dirty hack anyway for most usages, as one rarely wants the full range.

Comment: for 11 you've got 5:6, 6:5, but for 12 you've got 6:6, 6:6 so probabilities for getting 11 and 12 are equal. Perhaps you meant to say 10 which can be achived with 5:5, 5:5, 6:4, 4:6 which is twice as likely.

Answer (score 36):

This is an answer to a clarification of the question made in comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30821874/1294207),

> the reason i was adding was to avoid '0' as the random number in my code. rand()+rand() was the quick dirty solution which readily came to my mind.

The problem was to avoid 0. There are (at least) two problems with the proposed solution. One is, as the other answers indicate, that `rand()+rand()` can invoke undefined behavior. Best advice is to never invoke undefined behavior. Another issue is there's no guarantee that `rand()` won't produce 0 twice in a row.

The following rejects zero, avoids undefined behavior, and in the vast majority of cases will be faster than two calls to `rand()`:

```
int rnum;
for (rnum = rand(); rnum == 0; rnum = rand()) {}
// or do rnum = rand(); while (rnum == 0);
```

Comment: What about `rand() + 1`?

Comment: @askvictor That could overflow (although it's unlikely).

Comment: @gerrit - depends on MAX_INT and RAND_MAX

Comment: @askvictor Oh, right.  I thought they would be the same, but that is not stated anywhere.  My mistake.

Comment: @gerrit, I would be surprised if they are _not_ the same, but I suppose this is a place for pedants :)

Comment: @askvictor - On my computer, with my compilers, `RAND_MAX` is `MAX_INT`. So adding one could overflow. Unlikely, but not impossible. I've used other systems where `RAND_MAX` is only 32767. There adding one cannot overflow.

Comment: @DavidHammen: 32767 + 1 == 0x8000, which  **is** actually overflow for 16 bit `int` (reason for this value of RAND_MAX might very well be some 16 bit legacy/function call). Please note that `int` can be very well 16 bit wide (and _is_ for many systems).

Comment: Unlikely but if your application generates 1 million random numbers per second it's going to happen some 20 times per day, assuming RAND_MAX==MAX_INT on a 32 bit system.

Comment: If RAND_MAX==MAX_INT, rand() + 1 will overflow with exactly the same probability as the value of rand() being 0, which makes this solution completely pointless. If you are willing to risk it and ignore the possibility of an overflow, you can as well use rand() as is and ignore the possibility of it returning 0.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes, thats an elegant solution.

Comment: @gerrit - "That could overflow (although it's unlikely)." Don't you mean "That *will* eventually overflow."

Comment: @KevinFegan Any event with $p>0$ will eventually happen if the experiment is repeated sufficiently often.  The two statements are identical.

Answer (score 3):

Basically `rand()` produce numbers between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, and `2 RAND_MAX > INT_MAX` in your case.

You can modulus with the max value of your data-type to prevent overflow. This ofcourse will disrupt the distribution of the random numbers, but `rand` is just a way to get quick random numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i=0;

    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
        printf(" %d : %d \n", rand(), ((rand() % (INT_MAX/2))+(rand() % (INT_MAX/2))));

    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
        printf(" %d : %ld \n", rand(), ((rand() % (LONG_MAX/2))+(rand() % (LONG_MAX/2))));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you could try rather a tricky approach by ensuring that the value returned by sum of 2 rand() never exceeds the value of RAND_MAX. A possible approach could be sum = rand()/2 + rand()/2; This would ensure that for a 16 bit compiler with RAND_MAX value of 32767 even if both rand happens to return 32767, even then (32767/2 = 16383) 16383+16383 = 32766, thus would not result in negative sum.

Comment: The OP wanted to exclude 0 from the results. The addition also does not provide a uniform distribution of random values.

Comment: @Olaf: There's no guarantee that two consecutive calls to `rand()` won't both yield zero, so a desire to avoid zero isn't a good reason for adding two values.  On the other hand, a desire to have a non-uniform distribution would be a good reason to add two random values if one ensures that overflow doesn't occur.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid 0, try this:

```
int rnumb = rand()%(INT_MAX-1)+1;
```

You need to include `limits.h`.

Comment: That will double the probability to get 1. It is basically the same (but possiblly slower) as conditionally adding 1 if `rand()` yields 0.

Comment: Yes, you are right Olaf. If rand() = 0 or INT_MAX -1 the rnumb will be 1.

Comment: Even worse, as I come to think about it. It will actually double the propability for `1` and `2` (all assumed `RAND_MAX == INT_MAX`). I did forget about the `- 1`.

Comment: The `-1` here serves no value.  `rand()%INT_MAX+1;`  would still only generate values  in the [1...INT_MAX] range.

Answer (score 1):

> the reason i was adding was to avoid '0' as the random number in my code. rand()+rand() was the quick dirty solution which readily came to my mind.

A simple solution (okay, call it a "Hack") which never produces a zero result and will never overflow is:

```
x=(rand()/2)+1    // using divide  -or-
x=(rand()>>1)+1   // using shift which may be faster
                  // compiler optimization may use shift in both cases
```

This will limit your maximum value, but if you don't care about that, then this should work fine for you.

Comment: Sidenote: Careful with right shifts of signed variables. It is only well-defined for nonnegative values, for negatives, it is implementation defined. (Luckily, `rand()` always returns a nonnegative value). However, I would leave the optimization to the compiler here.

Comment: @Olaf: In general, signed division by two will be less efficient than a shift.  Unless a compiler writer has invested effort in telling the compiler that `rand` will be non-negative, the shift will be more efficient than division by a signed integer 2.  Division by `2u` could work, but if `x` is an `int` may result in warnings about implicit conversion from unsigned to signed.

Comment: @supercat: Please read my comment car3efully again. You should very well know any reasonable compiler will use a shift for `/ 2` anyway (I've seen this even for something like `-O0`, i.e. without optimisations explicitly requested). It's possibly the most trivial and most established optimisation of C code. Point is the division is well defined by the standard for the whole integer range, not only non-negative values. Again: leave optimsations to the compiler, write **correct** and clear code in the first place. This is even more important for beginners.

Comment: @Olaf: Every compiler I've tested generates more efficient code when shifting `rand()` right by one or dividing by `2u` than when dividing by 2, even when using `-O3`.  One might reasonably say such optimization is unlikely to matter, but saying "leave such optimizations to the compiler" would imply that compilers would be likely to perform them.  Do you know of *any* compilers that actually will?

Comment: @supercat: You should use more modern compilers then. gcc just generated fine code the last time I checked the generated Assembler. Nevertheless, as much I apprechiate to have a groopie, I'd prefer not to be harrassed to the extend you present the last time. These posts are years old, my comments are perfectly valid. Thank you.

Comment: @Olaf: I just checked gcc 8.1 and clang 6.0 on godbolt.  Given `int rdiv2a(void) { return rand()/2; }
int rdiv2b(void) { return rand()>>1; }` they produce 8 or 9 instructions (respectively) for rdiv2a, while producing 5 for rdiv2b.  Using `/2` isn't "leaving optimizations up to the compiler", it's deciding to do without them.  In most cases, such optimizations won't matter, but one should be aware that's what one is doing.

Comment: @supercat: Yes, it seems to do this to handle the negative case correctly. But it does **not** use a division as you probosed. The two additional instructions are at most 1 clock cycle each (they can likely be folded in a non-synthetic program, but even if not, it is completely irrelevant here), btw. If you want to have no difference, use `unsigned`, which is as fine for `rand()` and the much better "optimisation" anyway here. Oh, and a different arch than x64 (which I used) could very well result in identical code for both. Btw: That's all I will discuss here. You're proposing bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

> thx. the reason i was adding was to avoid '0' as the random number in my code. rand()+rand() was the quick dirty solution which readily came to my mind

It sounds like an XY problem to me, in which in order to not get a 0 from `rand()`, you call `rand()` two times, doing the program slower, with a new setback and the possibility of getting a 0 is still there.

Another solution is using [`uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), which creates a random and uniformly distributed number in the defined interval:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/QKIHG4ghwJf1b7ZN

```
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    const int MAX_VALUE=50;
    const int MIN_VALUE=1;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
    std::array<int,MAX_VALUE-MIN_VALUE> weight={0};

    for(int i=0; i<50000; i++) {
        weight[distrib(gen)-MIN_VALUE]++;
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<(int)weight.size();i++) {
        std::cout << "value: " << MIN_VALUE+i << " times: " << weight[i] << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

While what everyone else has said about the likely overflow could very well be the cause of the negative, even when you use unsigned integers. The real problem is actually using time/date functionality as the seed. If you have truly become familiar with this functionality you will know exactly why I say this. As what it really does is give a distance (elapsed time) since a given date/time. While the use of the date/time functionality as the seed to a rand(), is a very common practice, it really is not the best option. You should search better alternatives, as there are many theories on the topic and I could not possibly go into all of them. You add into this equation the possibility of overflow and this approach was doomed from the beginning.

Those that posted the rand()+1 are using the solution that most use in order to guarantee that they do not get a negative number. But, that approach is really not the best way either.

The best thing you can do is take the extra time to write and use proper exception handling, and only add to the rand() number if and/or when you end up with a zero result. And, to deal with negative numbers properly. The rand() functionality is not perfect, and therefore needs to be used in conjunction with exception handling to ensure that you end up with the desired result.

Taking the extra time and effort to investigate, study, and properly implement the rand() functionality is well worth the time and effort. Just my two cents. Good luck in your endeavors...

Comment: `rand()` does not specify what seed to use. The standard _does_ specify it to use a pseudorandom generator, not a relation to any time. It also does not state about the qualitiy of the generator. The actualy problem is clearly the overflow. Note that `rand()+1` is used to avoid `0`; `rand()` does not return a negative value. Sorry, but you did miss the point here. It is not about the quality of the PRNG. ...

Comment: ... Good practice under GNU/Linux its to seed from `/dev/random` and use a good PRNG afterwards (not sure about the quality of `rand()` from glibc) or continue using the the device - risking your application to block if there is not enough entropy available. Trying to get your entropy in the application might very well be a vulnerability as that is possibly easier to attack. And now it comes to hardening - not here