# C shellsorting random int array

Tags: c, shellsort

I've run into a problem when writing simple program to shellsort array of random numbers. Program doesn't sort it, just prints 1,1,1,1,1 or 0,0,0,0,0 even though shellsort algorithm is from rosettacode so it should be correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void shell_sort (int *a, int n) {
    int h, i, j, t;
    for (h = n; h /= 2;) {
        for (i = h; i < n; i++) {
            t = a[i];
            for (j = i; j >= h && t < a[j - h]; j -= h) {
                a[j] = a[j - h];
            }
            a[j] = t;
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int i;
    int array[100000];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % 1000 + 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d%\n", array[i]);

    shell_sort(array, 100000);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d%\n", array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're generating 100,000 random numbers in the range 1 - 1000, then only looking at the first five. The first 100 of them are probably all 1. Try your code with a list of 10 numbers first.

Comment: @koper I have illustrated what Bill the Lizard said. Should be useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of your program in my system is :

94
76
444
792
967
1
1
1
1
1

Another instance gives output:

665
777
481
269
215
1
1
1
1
1

So, you could guess that the random numbers generated must have a lot of ones.

However, if I change this piece of your code:

```
for (i = 10; i < 10005; i++)
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);

shell_sort(array, 100000);

for (i = 10; i < 1005; i++)
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
```

The output is:

8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10

The problem is not in the algo but the way you generate the random numbers.

I just change this line further,

```
 for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() + 1;  // Removed the modulus
    }
```

And the output is:

228
228
228
229
229
229
229
229
229
230
230
230
232
232
232
233
233
234
234
236
236
236
236
237
237
237
237
237
237
238
238
238
238
239
239
239
240
240
241
241
241
241
241
242
242
242
243
244
245
245
245
245
245
245
245
246
246
248
248
248
249
249
249
249
250
250
250
250
250
250
251
251
252
253
253
253
253
253
254
254
255
256
256
257
257
257
257
259
259
260
260
261
261
261
261
262
262
262
262
263
264
264
264
265
265
265
266
266
266
266
266
266
267
267
267
267
267
267
268
268
269
269
269
269
270
270
270
270
271
272
272
272
273
273
273
274
275
275
275
275
276
276
277
277
277
277
277
277
279
279
279
279
279
280
280
280
280
280
280
280
280
280
281
281
281
281
282
282
283
283
284
284
284
285
285
285
286
286
287
287
287
287
287
288
289
289
289
289
289
290
290
291
291
292
292
292
293
293
293
294
294
294
295
295
295
295
295
296
296
297
297
298
298
298
298
298
299
299
299
299
300
300
300
300
300
301
301
303
303
303
304
304
304
305
305
305
305
306
306
307
308
308
309
310
310
310
311
311
311
311
312
312
312
313
314
314
314
314
316
316
316
316
316
316
317
317
317
317
317
317
318
319
319
319
319
320
320
321
321
321
322
322
322
322
326
326
326
326
326
327
327
327
328
328
329
329

So, everything is fine. Just use the random numbers in a better way.

Comment: If `RAND_MAX == INT_MAX`, which is likely, the addition of `1` to a signed integer generates overflow if `RAND_MAX` is returned. That is  _undefined behaviour_. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821406/why-does-rand-rand-produce-negative-numbers/30821874#30821874).