# Random value with min and max, and with value leaning on center over value

Tags: javascript, math

I tried to follow those post

[Get a random number focused on center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492259/get-a-random-number-focused-on-center)

[Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

I have a minimum value A ex : -100
I have a maximum value B ex : 100
I have a dispersionLevel C ([0, 1])

what I would like is

when `C = 1`, I can generate a random value between `-100*1=-100` and `100*1=100`, but with a high tendency to be in the range of `(-100*1)*0.5=-50` and `(100*1)*0.5=50`

When `C = 0.5`, I can generate a random value between `-100*0.5=-50` and `100*0.5=50` but with a high tendency of being in the range of `(-100*0.5)*0.5=-25` and `(100*0.5)*0.5=25`

When `C = 0`, I can generate a random value between `-100*0` and `100*0` but with a high tendency of being in the range of `(-100*0)*0.5=0` and `(100*0)*0.5=0`

This because, I have a center point, the more I am close to this center point, the more dispersed the value can be, but the more distant I am, the less dispersed those value can be.

I was about to use a bell like the examples, they highly increase the probability that it goes to the center, but I can still have value that will go occasionally outside of the borders.

That is why, the more I go far, the more the range will also shrink.

Here is my broken fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/hums08pg/1/